# Error running ensime-source-buffer-loaded-hook - OSX with ENSIME and Emacs

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

I get the following error when trying to start ENSIME on OSX through Emacs

```
Error running ensime-source-buffer-loaded-hook
```

I am following the instructions from the [github source page](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime)

1. Scala Mode is Working
2. ENSIME Server *appears* to be installed, is there any way to verify this?
3. The `sbt` plugin is installed and I have a `.ensime` config file generated

Starting Emacs gives me the above error. When I manually try `M-x ensime` I get the following:

```
Failed to connect to Swank: server process exited.
```

Comment: More info needed. put `(setq debug-on-error t)` and add trace information to your question.

Comment: I could not get the debugger start using that command, I inserted (debug 'debug) right before the line that produces the error test https://gist.github.com/2300260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's how I solved it:

Locate the `ensime` folder and run `bin/server /tmp/ensime.port`.
I got the error:

```
java -classpath ... org.ensime.server.Server ./port
Unrecognized VM option '+DoEscapeAnalysis'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I have no idea what `DoEscapeAnalysis` is for, but I tried deleting it from `bin/server` and now everything seems to work.

See here: https://gist.github.com/2300737

Comment: There is a mandatory waiting-period for marking your own answers correct. I will do so when that's up.

Answer (score 1):

For my case on Windows 7, with the same error message, but the root cause was the original  setting for the maximum heap size -Xmx1512M was too large, I had to change to -Xmx768M to get over the error message.

I had also removed the byte compiled elisp code, and restart to avoid another error of 
"call time out".

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error on linux with emacs 24.3.1 and resolved it by specifying the full path to java in bin/server.